# Asp.net breakpoints not being hit but able to step into the same code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm developing a web site and a web service(which the web site calls) in the same solution with Visual Studio 2012/c#.  If I set breakpoints in the web site code they get hit but if I set breakpoints within the web service they don't get hit.  Now the strange thing is that stepping into the web service from the web site works.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can set *multiple* projects to be Startup projects (Right-click Solution in Solution Explorer, Properties, Common Properties, Startup Project, switch the radio button to Multiple Startup Projects and choose to start both of your projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your web service project as your "Startup Project". Set breakpoints and run.

Comment: If I set the web service as the startup project it doesn't run anything, just displays a directory listing (because a web service doesn't have an automatic entry point).  The web site needs to be the startup probject.

Comment: From the directory list in your browser, you can invoke the method and this will trigger the breakpoint(s) set.

Comment: Ok as explained by Damien I need to set both the web site and web service as startup projects.